# php combining square brackets in variable names

Tags: php

I have a variable from a select query

```
$row[red]
```

I would like to use this variable as a key in an array. The array is

```
$list[]
```

So I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
$list[$row[red]]
```

The above however does not work. I have tried:

```
$list[{$row[red]}]
```

and

```
$list[($row[red])]
```

but of course they don't work either.

The exact code I am using:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT entity, language FROM words WHERE entity IN ($entities) AND language = $_GET[site] AND id NOT IN ($ids)");
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{
$temporary = $row2[entity];
echo"$row2[entity] <a href='index.php?    m=$row2[entity]&l=$row2[language]&site=$_GET[site]'>$wordarray[$temporary]</a>      (${'e'.$languagearray[$temporary]}) <br>";

}
```

I am using $temporary as a bridging variable.

Comment: `$list[$row['red']]` is valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example to use -

```
$row = array('red'=>'test');
$list = array();
$list[$row['red']] = 'your value';
echo "<pre>";print_r($list);
```

The output will be -

```
Array
(
    [test] => your value
)
```

Comment: This is how I am using it now, but I would like to avoid using a bridging variable.

Comment: Please check example above in my answer if you want to do like that.

Comment: the line $list[$row['red']] = 'your value'; throws a syntax error